# How do I sell my photos at art festivals?

Tags: selling, licensing

How do I sell my photos at art festivals?

- Do I need a license in NY?  If so, what license?
- What age can I get this license or start selling?
- Can I use my own booth or do I have to purchase one of theirs?

Comment: It's probably going to depend on the terms of each art festival as to what is required. I'm not posting as an answer as I'm outside of the US and I don't know what other laws apply to selling

Answer (score 3):

Most of those answers will depend on the organization/group that is putting on the festival.  Some festivals may be free, others may require a license.  At a minimum, you should have a Business license that is valid in the state of New York if you are going to be selling things.

As far as age, you'll have to be at least 18 to sign a contract.  If you are under 18, you could possibly get around this if you had a partner that was over 18, like a parent, who could sign all the agreements.  They would likely need to be present at the art festival for legal reasons.  Again, you'll have to check with the art festival coordinator to get specifics on their requirements.